# Best time to plant red potatoes

Tags: planting, potatoes

About a year ago, I kept some red potatoes in the cellar. Most of them were edible, but some of them began sprouting so I didn't eat them. Now, I want to plant these remaining potatoes in the garden. When is the best time to do this in Israel? Should I wait for the rain season?

Comment: If I read your profile correctly you're in Israel?

Comment: Any images you can add of the sprouting potatoe's?

Comment: @GardenerJ yes, you read correctly

Answer (score 3):

Gotta know where you live, what kind of soil but assuming you have a winter season I would keep those potatoes cool and dry for now.  Store in sawdust in a cellar?  Store in shredded newspaper in a cool cellar?  Plant in early spring.  You can cut into halves/quarters as long as they have 'eyes'.  Plant in soil that is not compacted nor retains water.  The pH needs to be more acidic...6.0 to be safe.  But planting store bought potatoes or using one's own potatoes for starts is a bit dangerous.  Best is to purchase certified disease free potatoes from a reputable source.  Depending on your soil condition and your zone, one could plant now and they'll grow in the spring.  Potatoes are easy to grow, so rewarding and one of the first 'products' of a vegetable garden.  The plants die back quicker than other plants in the vegetable garden.  The potatoes will be fine as long as your soil is very light, full of organic material, pH is correct, no potatoes/tomatoes planted in the same soil for at least 2 years (disease), watered regularly, fertilized.  Lots of light.  Share pictures and more detail to get better, more personalized answers....